# UISegmentedControl setFrame not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add segmented control to tableviewheader. I am using the following code to do that

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ALL", @"HOUSE", @"SENATE", nil]];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(24, 0, 272, 30);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];    
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl;
```

I can't set the frame, no matter what value is put its always 100% wide. How can i set the add 24px margin on left and right ?

Comment: Here you applying `UISegmentControl` to `UITableView` header thats why it take full width. You need to create `UIView` for header and than add segmentControl to this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using the segment control as a tableHeaderView. a UITableViewHeaderView will be always be as wide as your tableView. You can only change the height.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are adding segmentedControl on controller view [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl] and then assigning it to table header view

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl;
```

Which is wrong, you need to create a view with size table header size and then add segmentedControl add on view and assign this view to table header view.

Example

```
**UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ALL", @"HOUSE", @"SENATE", nil]];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(24, 0, 272, 30);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];    
[view addSubview:segmentedControl];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;**
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to `akshaynhegde` answer, you can easily achieve this by adding an extra `UIView` as parent and add the UISegmentControl to that `UIView`. In this case the parent `UIView` will take the whole width of `UITableView` but not the `UISegmentControl`.

So following should be the change in your code

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,30.0)];
[view addSubview:segmentedControl];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

It should solve your problem.

Cheers.